# installation of docker on ubuntu: unable to connect to github.com

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am using [this guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) to install docker on an ubuntu server; below is a list of commands that succeed:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
$(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
apt-cache madison docker-ce
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=5:20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-focal docker-ce-cli=5:20.10.5~3-0~ubuntu-focal containerd.io
sudo docker run hello-world
```

and the following command ends with an exception which I could not figure out. I am just appending the last few lines of the output, i.e. there several more lines like 'Pull complete' which for simplicity are not pasted.

```
$ sudo docker build . --rm -t unet_industrial:latest
...
64b042356f2f: Pull complete 
cc20fc4ac4a7: Pull complete 

  Running command git clone -q git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger /tmp/pip-install-qk44vpx2/dllogger_fe6a3cc31bd747099e88bb9266898680
  fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
  github.com[0: 140.82.121.3]: errno=Connection timed out

WARNING: Discarding git+git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger#egg=dllogger. Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger /tmp/pip-install-qk44vpx2/dllogger_fe6a3cc31bd747099e88bb9266898680 Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dllogger (unavailable)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dllogger (unavailable)
```

In addition, I am posting here the Dockerfile which ought to be changed because it was ascertained that the git clone command works upon using https:// in lieu of git://

```
ARG FROM_IMAGE_NAME=nvcr.io/nvidia/tensorflow:20.06-tf1-py3
FROM ${FROM_IMAGE_NAME}

WORKDIR /opt
COPY requirements.txt /opt/requirements_unet_tf_industrial.txt

RUN python -m pip --no-cache-dir --no-cache install --upgrade pip && \
    pip --no-cache-dir --no-cache install -r /opt/requirements_unet_tf_industrial.txt

ENV TF_EXTRA_PTXAS_OPTIONS="-sw200428197=true"

ADD . /workspace/unet_industrial
WORKDIR /workspace/unet_industrial
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's proxy related as you're able to pull apt packages and execute curl commands. Perhaps it's related to SSH (perhaps not configured) - can you try cloning repo using HTTPS instead e.g. `git clone -q https://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger.git /tmp/pip-install-qk44vpx2/dllogger_fe6a3cc31bd747099e88bb9266898680`

let me know how it goes...

Comment: the instruction `git clone -q https://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger.git /tmp/pip-install-qk44vpx2/dllogger_fe6a3cc31bd747099e88bb9266898680 ` succeeds and a directory `/tmp/pip-install-qk44vpx2/dllogger_fe6a3cc31bd747099e88bb9266898680/ ` is indeed created. So presumably I need to modify my Dockerfile but I do not know how

Comment: If you add your Dockerfile to you're original question, I'll be able to tell you what you need to change... but you can probably just search and replace `git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger` with `https://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger.git`

Comment: Other thing you could do is configure SSH in your Dockerfile, but that would be trickier than just changing git clone from SSH to HTTPS.

Comment: I have modified the requirements.txt file: `diff requirements.txt requirements.txt.old
1c1
< git+https://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger#egg=dllogger
---
> git+git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger#egg=dllogger
`and that appears to work

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to install of docker on ubuntu, but related to your projects' Dockerfile build.

From your error log, it looks there are next in your Dockerfile:

> pip install git+git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger

When pip install from a github repo, it will first try to download the source code with:

> git clone -q git://github.com/NVIDIA/dllogger

Unfortunately, when docker do build it will also start a build container, but looks your build container can't visit github.

A probable reason is you are behind a proxy, then you need add proxy when build like next:

```
$ docker build --build-arg http_proxy=your_http_proxy --build-arg https_proxy=your_https_proxy -t unet_industrial:latest .
```